# Download the directory structure of a website without its files?

Tags: wget

I googled for this but couldn't find an example of how to use eg. wget to download the directory structure of a website without downloading any of its files.

At this point, I just need to understand how a website is organized. I'll mirror the site later.

Comment: Do you mean the directory structure as in where the images, css, and js are stored?

Comment: Yes, the directory structure, eg. /dir1, /dir2, etc.

Comment: This isn't clear.  Do you mean the directory structure of the assets that make up the site, such as where the images and css etc files reside, or do you mean the tree structure that describes how the pages link together (which is not related to directory structure).  What for example would be in "dir1" in this case?

Comment: This looks very relevant to web crawl the list of web pages on a particular web site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857653/get-a-list-of-urls-from-a-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the command prompt type:

```
wget -r --spider www.your-website.com
```

Alternate command with an option to specify the maximum depth level depth.

```
wget -r --spider -l depth www.your-website.com
```

Recursive retrieval options:

```
-r  
--recursive
    Turn on recursive retrieving.    The default maximum depth is 5.

--spider
    Don't download anything

-l depth
--level=depth
    Specify recursion maximum depth level depth.
```

Comment: but this _does_ download the files, too.

Comment: The `--spider` option of `wget` doesn't download anything except for creating the empty directory structure of the URL without downloading any files into the directories.

Comment: Somehow, I read over that argument.  My bad.